# Use of Alpha Numeric Phonenumbers

Tags: human-interface-guideline, phone-numbers

On Apple's developer site, I read this,

> For up-and-running support, please contact AppleCare at 1-800-MY-APPLE.

Will users understand how to use this format ?

Comment: I’ve been long pondering with the idea to create an Open Type font that had a feature to show digits atop letters for just this purpose (kind of Asian ruby notation, e.g. Japanese furigana). Never had the time or actual need, though. These are also known as “vanity numbers” in some places.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a user asking what letters in telephone numbers mean. In order for this question to stand, it should rather ask for the UX benefits/implications of presenting a number in this way.

Comment: It's quite a worthwhile UX question - but it yes it needs rewording (which I've just done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as [Phonewords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword) where the letters refer to the letters on some telephone keypads such as this:-

[image: Telephone keypad]

So the MY APPLE portion would be 69 27753

Apple have local numbers within most countries that they operate, so if you are outside the US it's probably best not to use the number.

EDIT: Some people have noted that younger users whose first phones don't have a keypad, might not be familiar with the concept though.

Comment: Spelling out words using the keypad is an American idea.  If you tried to do it in the UK nobody would know what it meant, despite the letters being on all phone keypads.

Comment: Agreed, although both of us are from the UK and knew about them.

Comment: @StephenKeable, Wow, really surprising of this. Your answer fulfilled my level of knowledge :)

Comment: There are a few UK examples including 0800 REVERSE and 0800 FOXTONS. I believe Smile used to have something like 0800 THEBANK too.

Comment: I doubt the UK examples would work for most of the UK population - it depends whether you've had contact with the American usage.  Texting on a mobile without a full keyboard makes you consider the use of the alphabetic keys on the phone keyboard - but contact with this will diminish now that people are using dedicated keyboards on smartphones.

Comment: Within the UK we see these used in American television and movies so I guess it depends on that exposure. However good point about smartphones without the keypad, would be interesting to see the use and recognition over time.

Answer (score 0):

As quite often in UX, this answer relays on culture and the pre-existing knowledge of such patterns. In western-Europe, this system never made it and therefore would be considered bad UX. If Phonewords are something that already exists in your country, you could probably try it.

But never forget: Especially kids have never ever seen a T9 phone keyboard. Therefore their mental model is most likely unable to "just get" this kind of number.

Long story short: If you can avoid it, avoid it.